# excel index match works when retype

Tags: excel

Index Match function Ecxel 2016 in text field works only when I re-type text. How to fix it? I have some correct result, but others look like needed retyping manually. No mistake in formula.

```
=INDEX(Sheet6!C:C,MATCH(TRIM(Sheet2!M6),Sheet6!D:D,0))
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Look for an invisible character in the original. CHAR(10) is typical in data copied from a website. `=unicode(mid(a$1, row(1:1), 1))` and fill down for the unicode of each character, invisible or not.

Comment: Finding a CHAR(160) or non-breaking space in place of a CHAR(32) is also common.

Comment: Have you checked the calculation mode of the worksheet? In ribbon `Formulas>Calculation>Calculation Options`, the tick shall be against `Automatic`.

Comment: Automatic calculation was checked, tnx.I tried to change characters by using =SUBSTITUTE(E1,CHAR(160),CHAR(32) ).It doesn't change result.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving whole range (i.e D:D), try within limited range once.

And can you explain your query here in details.